# pandas: fillna(method="pad") "NaN" values but not "None"

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to (forward) fill only "NaN" values and not "None"?. For example, I have a df:

```
   A     B     C
0  12    0    None
1  None  NaN  None
2  NaN   9.8  1
3  0     NaN  1
```

Appyling `df.fillna(method="pad")` will replace all NaN AND None values. I want to exclude "None" values from the fill ops and leave them unchanged.

Expected:

```
   A     B     C
0  12    0   None
1  None  0   None
2  None  9.8  1
3  0     9.8  1
```

Comment: What you expect is what I got by running your code.

Comment: Note that you might want `df.ffill` or `df.bfill` too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `replace` then `ffill`

```
yourdf = df.replace({None:'None'}).ffill().replace({'None':None})
      A    B     C
0    12  0.0  None
1  None  0.0  None
2  None  9.8     1
3     0  9.8     1
```

Answer (score 0):

DataFrame:

```py
df = df.fillna(value=np.nan)
```

Series/Column:

```py
df.mycol.fillna(value=np.nan, inplace=True)
```

You can also use the `replace` method:

```py
df['column'].replace('None', np.nan, inplace=True)
```