# Pandas filling NaN values with a string value and keeping None values as the same

Tags: python, pandas, nan, nonetype, fillna

I have a dataframe with mixed datatypes. I would like to fill NaN values but keep None values as the same.

I tried to use fillna() method from pandas but the function is filling both NaN and None values.
I want to fill NaN with a specific string value like 'x', instead of numbers. And keep None values as the same.

```
For example:
   A     B     C
0  12    0    None
1  None  NaN  None
2  NaN   9.8  1
3  0     NaN  1

Expected:
   A     B     C
0  12    0    None
1  None  x    None
2  x     9.8  1
3  0     x    1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70477109/pandas-fillnamethod-pad-nan-values-but-not-none

Comment: @venkatakrishnan I checked that post and it is not the same problem. I'm trying to fill NaN values with string values. I tried the solution from that post but it didnt work.

Comment: @PV8  I checked that post and it is not the same problem. I'm trying to fill NaN values with string values. I tried the solution from that post but it didnt work.

Comment: The underlying logic is the same, and the answers you were given here use fundamentally the same technique. We do not require "duplicates" here to be asking an identical question; we only require them to have essentially the same answer - this requires understanding the solution that was described and trying to apply it in a way that makes sense ins context, not just copying and pasting. See for example https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384711 on Meta.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[None, 3], ["", np.nan]]) #created a dummy dataframe with these values
```

and then use this below code segment to change None to 'None' (a string) and then replace NA with which ever values you want to replace it with.

the finally converting it back to None (not a string)

```
df.replace({None:'None'}).fillna("x").replace({'None':None})
```

result looks like this

```
0 None  3.0 
1       x
```

Comment: In the created dummy dataframe that method works. But my original dataframe created from an xml file with read_xml() function. And when I try that method for it, replace({None:'None'}), it also replaces NaN values to None.

Answer (score 0):

If `df`is your dataframe:

```
df = df.replace({None:'None'}).fillna('x')
```

In the first step you will replace the `None` with a string 'None', then in the second step you will fill `NaN` with the string 'x'.

If the `NaN` are also identified as `None` try:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.replace({np.nan: 'x'})
```

followed by [Replacing Pandas or Numpy Nan with a None to use with MysqlDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162723/replacing-pandas-or-numpy-nan-with-a-none-to-use-with-mysqldb)

Comment: when we use replace({None:'None'}), it also replaces NaN values to None. Therefore fillna('x') methot is not working for any of them since they are not None anymore, but a string('None'). It is remaning as None for both NaN and None rows at the end.

Comment: How can you mark a solution then, which is applying the same function?